# HTML Video not always playing in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

When loading the page (clicking on index.html), the video doesn't play. After hitting F5 a couple times it does play. Whenever I open the index.html file the video almost never plays.

The video is stuck on the first frame when loading up, like a picture. After refreshing 1/2 times it does play but NEVER on the first load.

This problem is on Google Chrome.

On firefox it works on the first load.

On Internet Explorer it also works on the first load.

```
<video id="vid" class="backvid" autoplay loop>
<source src="assets/vids/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This is the code I have used. I have no idea how to post a jsfiddle or a snippet for this problem, since it contains a video. Maybe it is possible to force refresh the video on load, but I have no idea how to code this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<video id="vid" class="backvid" autoplay loop>
    <source src="assets/vids/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<style>
   .backvid{
     display:none;
   }
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".backvid").show();
});
</script>
```

For some reason if you add `.show()` it will work.

You must use `jQuery` in order for this solution to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script> 
    document.getElementById('vid').play(); 
</script>
```

Could you add that after `</video>` to see if it works?

Comment: This worked in my case (don't forget to call `.play()` sometime in or after `loadeddata` has fired). I guess Chrome just ignores the "autoplay" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You clear your chrome browser history and check it again. Because in my browser I face same issue and after clearing history my video

Comment: check your chrome version id updated or not? use updated version of chrome

Comment: also check any extension you use in chrome that may be affect on video autoplaying .

Comment: It also does not work on other devices, I tried 5 different laptops / pc's with the same result.

Comment: can you check your chrome extensions?

Comment: I only use adblocker at the moment

Comment: which add blocker ? Can you tell me name of that add blocker?

Comment: AdBlock. But i'll have to remind you that I have tried on 5 other devices with the same result.

Comment: then you fisrt remove or disable adblock extension and after that clear history of chrome after that open new window and run your code .